# Spring3 MultiActionController method - handler resolve. MapAndView vs String

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3

First, a bit of context:

**web.xml:**

I match all /app/* requests to my dispatcher:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My question, why does calling /app/import/view work when returning String:

**Controller:**

```
public class ImportController extends MultiActionController {

    public String view(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
        return "importer.home";
    }
```

but NOT when returning ModelAndView:

```
public class ImportController extends MultiActionController {

    public ModelAndView view(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("importer.home");
        mav.addObject(new ExlFile());
        return mav;
    }
```

Is there a different naming convention if we use ModelAndView?

Comment: Do you use Spring 3 or Spring 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `MultiActionController`, which has very strict constraints on method naming conventions and signatures.

However, you shouldn't be using `MultiActionController` at all, it's obsolete and deprecated. Write controllers as described in the Spring manual, i.e. using `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping`, then you get much more flexible method signatures.

Comment: Annotations it is then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring 3.0, then i will prefer to use annotation.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value  = "/app")
public class ImportController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/importer/home")
    public ModelAndView view(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("importer.home");
        mav.addObject(new ExlFile());
        return mav;
    }
```